# Add a variable from array of objects and combine them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to add a variable from array of objects and combine them.

Example data :

```
    const item = [{
                "act": "Q",
                "line": 1,
                "qty": 6,
                "type": 00
},
{
                "act": "Q",
                "line": 1,
                "qty": 6,
                "type": 00
},
{
                "act": "Q",
                "line": 2,
                "qty": 6,
                "type": 00
},
{
                "act": "Q",
                "line": 2,
                "qty": 4,
                "type": 00
}]
```

I want to check if act is Q and type is 00 then get the output with line and sum of qty for the line.

```
    [{
                "line": 1,
                "qty": 12,
},
{
                "line": 2,
                "qty": 10,
}]
```

Comment: ① Please make sure you provide a [mre] that doesn't have problems you're not asking about. `00` is not a valid numeric literal in TypeScript.  Do you just mean `0` or is it supposed to be a string? ② What have you tried, yourself, to solve the problem? This is likely to be simple-ish loop or reduce, so it would be more instructive to future readers to understand exactly where confusion around this task is coming from.

Comment: why do you need to check `act` and `type`? you data is already filtered. do you have different data?

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you would want to do is use the `Array.filter` function and set in the parameters to get what you want.

Something like this

```
let a = item.filter(ele => ele.act == "Q" && ele.type == 00);

console.log(a)
```

the variable `a` would now contain all your objects, you can iterate it and print whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

for your input:

```
const item = [
  { "act": "Q", "line": 1, "qty": 6, "type": 00 },
  { "act": "Q", "line": 1, "qty": 6, "type": 00 },
  { "act": "Q", "line": 2, "qty": 6, "type": 00 },
  { "act": "Q", "line": 2, "qty": 4, "type": 00 }
];
```

To filter by act and type you can use `Array.filter()` method like this:

```
const filteredByActAndType = item.filter(i => i.act === 'Q' && i.type === 00)
```

then to sum the qty you can use `Array.reduce()` method like this:

```
const reducedArray = filteredByActAndType.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const line = acc.find(i => i.line === cur.line)
  if (line) {
    line.qty += cur.qty
  } else {
    acc.push({line: cur.line, qty: cur.qty})
  }
  return acc
}, [])
```

output will be exact what you need:

```
[
    {
        "line": 1,
        "qty": 12
    },
    {
        "line": 2,
        "qty": 10
    }
]
```

Comment: Since you are already using reduce you can do the filtering in the reduce and get a bit more efficiency

Answer (score 0):

You could group by `line` and then get total of `qty` for every group.

```js
const
    items = [{ act: "Q", line: 1, qty: 6, type: "00" }, { act: "Q", line: 1, qty: 6, type: "00" }, { act: "Q", line: 2, qty: 6, type: "00" }, { act: "Q", line: 2, qty: 4, type: "00" }],
    grouped = Object
        .values(Object.groupBy(items, ({ line }) => line))
        .map(a => ({ line: a[0].line, qty: a.reduce((t, { qty }) => t + qty, 0) }));

console.log(grouped);
```